# AngularJS API call to remote API returning ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID - showing Incorrect Certification Path

Tags: c#, angularjs, ssl, iis, cross-domain

We recently setup a centralized API that we do user auth through. The front end is AngularJS the backend is C#.

Our front end site mysite1.com attempts to authentic over angularjs to C# to our centralized api api.mysite2.com.

After deploying - we have *some* users reporting they are unable to login. Many others have logged in successfully. However these last few users i'm unable to pinpoint the exact cause.

I was able to screenshare with one said user and found out that the our certificate is showing as insecure. It's also showing "ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" in the console.

Here is the console error:

[image]

When investigating the certificate in question on the users machine we see the following:

[image]

Here is more info on the "CA Root Certificate" from that users machine:

[image]

The weird thing, when we view that exact same cert on a users machine that works we see the following certification path, if you notice, this certification path has the correct root certs/etc.

[image]

I'm at a complete loss on what could cause this, or how to even fix this. The uses machine cert path is completely different - we have other users reporting login issues and i'm betting there is something similar going on with them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - we are in a tough position at the moment.

Comment: The incorrect root cert looks just like a self-signed certiciate. So have you enabled Server name indication on your Web server? Besides, It sounds like there was something wrong with the certifcate store on client side. have you tried to export then import intermediate certificate and root certificate to client side?

Comment: Hi - i dont believe we enabled SNI - but i'm not totally familiar with it- looking into it now. Unfortunately the clients machine is a customer of ours, so we are limited in our ability to debug their machine outside of taking screenshots. Do you know why they would have a self signed certificate instead of it pulling the default like most other browsers are?

Comment: Its strange that your certifiate is display a self-signed certificate as a issuer. Since we never seen this before. So it should be either server send the incorrect cert  with incorrect issuer or the client side  reolve the incorrect certificate chain.